# Write file on sdcard from AudioSystem (C++ code) in Android 5.0.1_r1

Tags: android, c++, system-calls, android-framework

I am trying to write a file in the sdcard of an Android device from AudioSystem.cpp. This is a service in the Android Framework. I am modifying the source code.

I am using the following code:

```
    int fd = open("/sdcard/file.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0666); 
    if(fd > -1) { 
     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "gxp18", "Writing to SDCARD");
         write(fd, "1", strlen("1")); 
         write(fd, "\n", 1); 
         close(fd); 
    } 
    else __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "gxp18", "ERROR while writing to SDCARD fd = %d", fd);
```

By running the code I always get fd = -1

The original code is the following:

```
status_t AudioSystem::startInput(audio_io_handle_t input,
                                 audio_session_t session)
{
    const sp<IAudioPolicyService>& aps = AudioSystem::get_audio_policy_service();

    if (aps == 0) return PERMISSION_DENIED;
    return aps->startInput(input, session);
}
```

The modified one is:

```
status_t AudioSystem::startInput(audio_io_handle_t input,
                                 audio_session_t session)
{
    const sp<IAudioPolicyService>& aps = AudioSystem::get_audio_policy_service();

    /* start */

    int fd = open("/sdcard/file.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, 0666); 
    if(fd > -1) { 
     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "gxp18", "Writing to SDCARD");
         write(fd, "1", strlen("1")); 
         write(fd, "\n", 1); 
         close(fd); 
    } 
    else __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "gxp18", "ERROR while writing to SDCARD fd = %d", fd);

    /* end */

    if (aps == 0) return PERMISSION_DENIED;
    return aps->startInput(input, session);
}
```

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission requested in manifest file?

Comment: What manifest file? This is not an Android App is part of the Android Framework (AOSP). I am modifying the source code.

Comment: Well than show the unmodified source code please.

Comment: Hmmm... i expected the original code to write a file to sdcard. But that was not there i see. On this low level it could be a permission problem. What does _lasterror, _error, _errno  of getlasterror() tell about it?There will be some info.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing to `/storage/emulated/0/file.txt`
Since JB the storage Dir has changed a bit.
I am assuming you're doing so from a system service

Comment: I am using a Nexus 5 device to test my code. In this case the path to the sdcard is /storage/sdcard0/file.txt. I double checked it by using adb. Unfortunately, I still get fd = -1